# Update only year in timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a timestamp column `start_date` in one model that I want to use to update the `start_date` column of another model but updates the will be only on `year` part for some records based on certain logic.
My code is something similar to this:

```
Model1.each do |record|
  model_2_instance = find_model2_record(record) # based on some logic
  diff = model_2_instance.start_date.year - record.start_date.year
  new_start_date = record.start_date - diff  # this won't work. I want a solution for this calculation.

  model_2_instance.update(start_date: new_start_date )
end
```

I want a solution for the `new_start_date` calculation in the above loop.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: nvm. `new_start_date = record.start_date - diff.years` worked.

Comment: _"based on certain logic"_ – you should _explain_ that logic. Maybe also give some example input and the expected output. What about edge cases where changing the year results in an invalid date? (February 29 on non-leap years)